# The second Insert does not work in my trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to learn more about triggers and I wrote a simple SQL code in MySQL.
This code will work with one insert but it will cause an error when I add the second insert.

I think the code that I wrote does not compile the second insert.

I would be appreciate for Any Help

Code:

```
create trigger MasterInputTRG
after insert on MasterInput
for each row
   insert into NewEMCtestPLAN(ProjectNumber,Manufacture,ModelName,`PO Number`,AccountExecutive,AENotes) values(NEW.ProjectNumber,NEW.Applicant,NEW.ModelName,NEW.PONumber,NEW.AccountExecutive,NEW.AENotes);
   insert into NewRF(ProjectNumber,Applicant,ModelName,PONumber,AccountExecutive,AENotes) values(NEW.ProjectNumber,NEW.Applicant,NEW.ModelName,NEW.PONumber,NEW.AccountExecutive,NEW.AENotes);
```

Error:

> Syntax error near 'insert into
>   NewEMCtestPLAN(ProjectNumber,Applicant,ModelName,PONumber,AccountExe'
>   at line 5

Update: 
I got an answer and I add the other code with errors here.:

Second Code that does not work:

```
create trigger MasterInputTRG
after insert on MasterInput
for each row
BEGIN
   insert into NewEMCtestPLAN(ProjectNumber,Manufacture,ModelName,`PO Number`,AccountExecutive,AENotes) values(NEW.ProjectNumber,NEW.Applicant,NEW.ModelName,NEW.PONumber,NEW.AccountExecutive,NEW.AENotes);
   insert into NewRF(ProjectNumber,Applicant,ModelName,PONumber,AccountExecutive,AENotes) values(NEW.ProjectNumber,NEW.Applicant,NEW.ModelName,NEW.PONumber,NEW.AccountExecutive,NEW.AENotes);
END
```

Errors:

> Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'NEW.ProjectNumber' in 'field
>   list'

But this error did not appear when i used the new.projectnumber in first insert.

second error:

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'END' at line 1

Comment: You need BEGIN and END

Comment: Hi I tried that to.But It does not work

Comment: You might also need to change the delimiter: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trigger body with multiple statements need to be surrounded bei `BEGIN` and `END`. But then (depending on your client) you might need to change the delimiter:

```
delimiter //

create trigger MasterInputTRG
after insert on MasterInput
for each row
begin
   insert into NewEMCtestPLAN (...) values (...);
   insert into NewRF (...) values (...);
end //

delimiter ;
```

The same applies to stored procedures and functions.

Note that the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement is a single.. well.. *statement*. Statements are delimited by.. well.. a *delimiter*. So in your original query the trigger definition ends with the first delimiter (`;`):

```
create trigger MasterInputTRG
after insert on MasterInput
for each row
   insert into NewEMCtestPLAN (...) values (...); -- trigger ends here
-- anything else is outside the trigger
   insert into NewRF (...) values (...);
```

The second insert could be a valid statement but outside the trigger definition. However I would expect a different error message like: `unknown table (alias) 'NEW'`, because `NEW` is not known outside the trigger.

Now if we change the delimiter to `//`, the create statement ends after the first occurance of `//`, so we can use `;` in the trigger body without terminating the CREATE statement.

Usually `//` or `$$` are used for a delimiter. You can try something else, but it should not have any meaning in (My)SQL. For example `|` is a [bit operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html).

Comment: It worked, Thanks. But I really do not know why i need to use delimiter and why i need to use '//' because I wrote the exact code with delimiter '|' and it did not work

Comment: @ChristianoMoshar See my update. `|` already has a meaning in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Begin` `End` in the trigger.

```
create trigger MasterInputTRG
after insert on MasterInput
for each row
   BEGIN
   insert into NewEMCtestPLAN(ProjectNumber,Manufacture,ModelName,`PO Number`,AccountExecutive,AENotes) values(NEW.ProjectNumber,NEW.Applicant,NEW.ModelName,NEW.PONumber,NEW.AccountExecutive,NEW.AENotes);
   insert into NewRF(ProjectNumber,Applicant,ModelName,PONumber,AccountExecutive,AENotes) values(NEW.ProjectNumber,NEW.Applicant,NEW.ModelName,NEW.PONumber,NEW.AccountExecutive,NEW.AENotes);
   END
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you,Sorry for the confusing. The second insert should be NewRF. I updated my code

Comment: Can I insert in two table in one trigger?

Comment: Thank you but it did not work. I will add your code to the question and also the errors

Comment: Yes, I updated the question. I really do appreciate for following up